# Make `npm ls somepackage` command respect version range

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm trying to use `npm ls` to find the source of security warnings. [The docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) mention that:

> Positional arguments are name@version-range identifiers, which will limit the results to only the paths to the packages named.

I'm fixing CVE-2020-7598 for package `minimist` which says:

> CVE-2020-7598
>   Vulnerable versions: < 0.2.1
>   Patched version: 0.2.1

Now `npm ls minimist` gives *all* dependencies tracked, but I want to do it for the specific range. So I've tried:

- `npm ls "minimist<0.2.1"` gives `The system cannot find the file specified.`
- `npm ls "minimist@<0.2.1"` gives `The system cannot find the file specified.`
- `npm ls "minimist@<=0.2.0"` gives `The system cannot find the file specified.`
- `npm ls "minimist@0.2.0"` gives `-- (empty)` (which makes sense because e.g. 0.0.8 is in my tree)

So, how can I make `npm ls` return packages below a certain version in my dependency tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synopsis for the command you want is as follows:

```
npm ls <pkg>@"<comparator>"
             ^            ^
```

**Note:** The double quotes are wrapped around the *comparator* part only.

For instance:

```
npm ls minimist@"<0.2.1"
                ^      ^
```

Any valid [semver range comparators](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#ranges) are permitted between the quotes. For example:

```
npm ls minimist@"<=0.2.0 >=0.0.8"
                ^               ^
```

Comment: Thx! Turns out in Powershell I _also_ needed _escaped_ quotes: `npm ls minimist@\`"<0.2.1\`"`